# getArguments().getInt() starts returning from "1", instead "0"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, bundle, realm

Please, help me in solving?

I have an `Activity` with `ViewPager` and 5 `RecyclerViewFragment`s, each of `RecyclerFragment` contains dynamic `CardView`s.

Code for `ViewPager` adapter:

```
public class CustomFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Board board;
    private long boardID;

    public CustomFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Board board, long id) {
        super(fm);
        this.board = board;
        this.boardID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return board.getMyLists().get(position).getName();
    }

    //Here I define fragment, int position - is a position of Fragment in ViewPager
    @Override
    public Fragment getFragment( int position) {
        **return RecyclerViewFragment.newInstance(boardID, position);**
    }
}
```

Next is newInstance of Fragment:

```
public static RecyclerViewFragment newInstance(long id, int listPosition){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(BUNDLE_ID, id);
    args.putInt(BUNDLE_LIST_POSITION, listPosition);
    RecyclerViewFragment fragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

I store **Fragment's position** via Bundle - `listPosition`

Then I get that position in OnCreateView through `getArguments()`

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    boardID = this.getArguments().getLong(BUNDLE_ID);
    listPosition = this.getArguments().getInt(BUNDLE_LIST_POSITION, 0);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
}
```

So the problem is, that when I get int-Position from getArguments(), it has next sequence - 1,2,3,4,0. But it writes in this order - 0,1,2,3,4

May be you think that it doesn't matter, but Realm ORM does reverse. When I get an info from DB about dynamic CardViews, Realm starts from 0th Fragment, while getArguments() from 1. And that thing throws

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

**[Update]** I added Log.d to newInstance and OnCreateView

```
public static RecyclerViewFragment newInstance(long id, int listPosition){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(BUNDLE_ID, id);
    Log.d(TAG, listPosition + " Before put");
    args.putInt(BUNDLE_LIST_POSITION, listPosition);
    Log.d(TAG, listPosition + " After put");
    RecyclerViewFragment fragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tinyDB = new TinyDB(getContext());
    boardPosition = tinyDB.getInt("boardPosition");
    boardID = this.getArguments().getLong(BUNDLE_ID);
    listPosition = this.getArguments().getInt(BUNDLE_LIST_POSITION, 0);
    Log.d(TAG, listPosition + " Get ");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
}
```

And in LogCat I get next:

```
06-12 00:37:46.188 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 0 Before put
06-12 00:37:46.188 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 0 After put
06-12 00:37:46.188 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 1 Before put
06-12 00:37:46.188 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 1 After put
06-12 00:37:46.188 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 2 Before put
06-12 00:37:46.188 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 2 After put
06-12 00:37:46.189 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 3 Before put
06-12 00:37:46.189 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 3 After put
06-12 00:37:46.189 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 4 Before put
06-12 00:37:46.189 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 4 After put
06-12 00:37:46.190 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 1 Get 
06-12 00:37:46.266 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 2 Get 
06-12 00:37:46.322 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 3 Get 
06-12 00:37:46.397 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 4 Get 
06-12 00:37:46.452 25265-25265/com.treggo.flexible D/mLogs: 0 Get
```

P.S. to bypass Exception, I set 9 CardViews, instead of reading it from Realm

Comment: Add +/- 1  at the appropriate spot? :D

Comment: The ViewPager loads both the current Fragment and the neighboring Fragments at the same time. I don't see how you could be getting 1 instead of 0 first

Comment: By the way, you should provide the logcat and the code that throws the error. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See creating a [mcve]*.

Comment: try this code  in oncreate...   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
         
            boardID = getArguments().getLong(BUNDLE_ID);
            listPosition = getArguments().getInt(BUNDLE_LIST_POSITION);
        }
    }

Comment: You expect a number to magical change before and after the put operation?

Comment: @WaqarYounis I've tried this before, but it didn't help me

Comment: @cricket_007 :) may be

Comment: Anyways, are you scrolling through the ViewPager to get these log messages? If not, and the ViewPager starts with position 0 loaded, then that is strange behavior that I haven't seen before.

Comment: I don't see Realm anywhere in this code. You should probably use `findAllSorted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i don't how you implemented the indexing of your list positions, from the problem i assume it starts from 1, rather than 0.

If this is the case, in your `newInstance()` method replace the following line:

```
args.putInt(BUNDLE_LIST_POSITION, listPosition);
```

with this:

```
args.putInt(BUNDLE_LIST_POSITION, listPosition - 1);
```